# compiling using libnids

Tags: gcc, libpcap

I have been trying to install **[libnids](http://libnids.sourceforge.net/)** (Ubuntu LTS and Mac OS X) all the day and now I know how to compile programs with it.

I write this here because there is not much documentation but there are samples in the libnids downloaded folder with a makefile. The important things of this makefile are these:

```
CC = gcc    
PCAPLIB     = -lpcap    
LNETLIB     = -lnet    
LIBS        = -L../src -lnids $(PCAPLIB) $(LNETLIB) -lgthread-2.0 -lnsl

example:
    $(CC) example.c -o example $(LIBS)
```

And if you're compiling it in Mac OS X ignore this: -lgthread-2.0 -lnsl -L../src
But I don't know if something stop to works because of these omitted things.

Comment: Don't worry if you get a warning during the library installation like this: **hash.c:18: warning: ignoring return value of ‘read’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result**

Comment: The only dependencies that you could need to install are: **libglib2.0-dev** [libnet1.1.2.1](http://packetfactory.openwall.net/libnet/dist/libnet.tar.gz) [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. The best way is to compile the library and then use local reference to the ".a" file.

**Makefile example**

```
CC = gcc -g -Wall 
GLIB =  `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
PCAPLIB     = -lpcap
LNETLIB     = -lnet

LIBS_SRC    = libnids-1.24/src/libnids.a
LIBS        = $(PCAPLIB) $(LNETLIB) -lgthread-2.0 

program: program.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) program.c -o program.o $(GLIB) $(LIBS)
    $(CC) program.o  -o program $(LIBS_SRC) $(GLIB) $(LIBS)
```

But if you want to compile the library and install it into your system you got to use **-lnids** instead of the above way. But the first solution always works.

Answer (score 1):

I got errors when compiling samples under libnids:

gcc -o overflows overflows.o  -L../src -lnids -lpcap -lnet -lgthread-2.0 -lnsl ../src/libnids.a
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libnids.a(libnids.o): undefined reference to symbol 'g_async_queue_pop'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [overflows] Error 1

You recommendation

```
GLIB =  `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
```

solves my problem.

PS： my system Ubuntu 13.10. 64bit.