# Libnids 64 bits systems

Tags: gcc, libpcap

My problem was that when I was compiling the app in a 64 bits Ubuntu I didn't get neither errors or warnings, just like in 32 bits, but there wasn't an output when executing it. Example:

```
$: ./program
$: _
```

But why!?

Comment: No but it's a contribution because there's not much documentation about this library and a lot of people with problems. It could be useful for people.

Comment: Ok! Self-answered questions are [allowed and encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) on Stack Overflow as long as they are useful and [follow the Q&A style](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103514/where-do-i-post-useful-howtos-for-different-topics). It is not obvious that your question is in fact a howto so it would be helpful if you changed it into a question and then posted the answer in the answer section. Otherwise I suspect that this post will be closed as "Not a real question".

Answer (score 3):

After many headaches and mail exchanges with the library's author I found the way to use libnids library on ubuntu 64 bits system.

Okay, I told the author and after some days he found the error. 
It was, apparently, a GCC error. 
It seems, for some reason, that you have to remove the -O2 flags when compiling libnids library on 64 bits systems.
So, what I've done is to remove the -O2 flags from the configure file so it creates a makefile without it.

I also recommend using this on your libnids app's Makefile: [compiling using libnids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399214/compiling-using-libnids/)